# Adding ARM template for virualNetworkRules for keyvault

Tags: azure, templates

I have my arm template as below for my keyvault but it doesnt do anything after deployment. Can anyone please shed a light? Thanks!

```
                        "networkAcls": {
                            "bypass": "AzureServices",
                            "defaultAction": "Deny",
                            "ipRules": [],
                            "virtualnetworkRules": [
                                {
                                    "id": "%RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME%/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/%RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME%-vnet/subnets/default",
                                    "ignoreMissingVNetServiceEndpoint": false
                                }
                            ]
                        }
```

Comment: I also tried to write id as:"id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', '%RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME%-vnet', 'default')]", but it doesnt work either.

Comment: can you try with "/subscriptions/" + SUBSCRIPTION_ID + "/resourceGroups/" + RESOURCE_GROUP + "/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/" + VIRTUAL_NETWORK_NAME + "/subnets/" + SUBNET_NAME + ""

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thanks but it didnt work :( I tried with powershell using `$myNetworkResId = (Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name d-datap-c0e-vnet -ResourceGroupName d-datap-c0e).Subnets[0].Id
echo $myNetworkResId
Add-AzKeyVaultNetworkRule -VaultName d-datap-c0e-app-kv -VirtualNetworkResourceId $myNetworkResId
` but after this, the networking still shows "Allow Access from All Networks"

Comment: Though if I query for the virtualnetworksrules it shows that it has been set. `(Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName "d-datap-c0e-app-kv").NetworkAcls` Question is how to let networking show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ARM template, it should be :

```
"networkAcls": {
    "bypass": "AzureServices",
    "defaultAction": "Deny",
    "ipRules": [],
    "virtualnetworkRules": [
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions/<azure sub id>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<vnet name>/subnets/<subnet name>",
            "ignoreMissingVNetServiceEndpoint": false
        }
    ]
}
```

If you are using AZ PowerShell, try `Update-AzKeyVaultNetworkRuleSet` as below:

```
  $vnetName = ''
  $vnetRG = ''
  $keyvaultName = ''

  $myNetworkResId = (Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $vnetRG).Subnets[0].Id 
  Update-AzKeyVaultNetworkRuleSet -VaultName $keyvaultName -Bypass AzureServices -DefaultAction Deny -VirtualNetworkResourceId $myNetworkResId
```

I have tested both of them, result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gong! I think it's our infrastructure deployment app has some problem because if I ran your powershell example it works perfect! Thanks again.